Google Colab Pro+ セッション数を増やす事は可能か
Google Colab Pro+ でランタイムはCPUを使用しているのですが、５つまでのセッションしか起動出来ません。
セッション数を増やす方法はあるでしょうか。

(参考) 過去の類似質問: Google colabを使って並列化計算の状況について
